# Uploaded app to Google Play but saying incompatible with device

Tags: android, xml, google-play

Hi I have uploaded my app to Google Play but however it says it's incompatible with my own device. I am struggling to understand why as I could run it fine during development. I have also tried downloading it on another device and it is also incompatible.

The XML file is exactly the same format as I have used for previous apps. No special permissions or anything. The file size is 3.5M. Has this happened to anyone before? Thanks in advance.

Edit: Also it says there are 0 excluded devices.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

-<manifest android:versionName="1.0.1" android:versionCode="2"  package="com.boxing.punch.android" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="19" android:minSdkVersion="8"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/> 
    <application android:theme="@style/GdxTheme" android:label="@string/app_name"    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:allowBackup="true"> 
      <activity android:name="com.boxing.punch.android.AndroidLauncher" android:label="@string/app_name" 
      android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" android:screenOrientation="portrait"> 
        <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
     </activity>
     <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity" 
android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
   </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Could you please show us your AndroidManifest.xml? Also please mention your device name. The Play Store compatibility filter is purely based on the content of your Manifest. It is irrelevant whether the app was developed and tested on your phone. E.g. if you have developed and tested your app on a Nexus 7 but haven't added 'supported-screens' in your Manifest, it will show as incompatible for your devices when you try to install it on your Nexus 7.

Comment: Also note that 'excluded devices' only are manually exluded devices, which you choose should not get the app update. Usually useful if you want to release an OEM-specific or phone-specific app. Your said device will be listed in the 'unsupported devices' section.

Comment: Put my xml on now, excuse the poor indentation. The xml file is exactly the same as previous apps I have done except the package etc obviously so I don't know how that could be an issue. Thank you.

Comment: shot in the dark, but why is there a hyphen before the manifest tag? Was it a copy paste error or was it in your original Manifest too?

Comment: Yeah sorry just a copy paste error.

Comment: It might be a [Google Play Store bug some people are facing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21730560/the-app-is-incompatible-with-all-your-devices). I checked your app and it is showing as incompatible with all of my 7 devices.

Comment: Ah ok, thanks for your help. I'll just wait it out and see if it changes or just upload it again.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably that your [app is too large](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10475954/why-does-the-google-play-store-say-my-android-app-is-incompatible-with-my-own-de):

> ... Currently the maximum file size limit for an app upload to Google Play is approximately 50 MB...
>
> ... some devices may have smaller than 50 MB cache partition making the app unavailable for users to download...

Try reducing your app's size

It could also be what some Instagram users have also had this problem. Instagram has suggested [this fix](https://help.instagram.com/231705083624002).

Answer (score 0):

It might be a [Google Play Store bug some people are facing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21730560/the-app-is-incompatible-with-all-your-devices). <strike>I checked your app and it is showing as incompatible with all of my 7 devices</strike>.

**UPDATE**: It is now showing as compatible with all my devices now.