# Android Developer Console compatibility report vs actual Play Store compatibility

Tags: android, google-play, wear-os, google-developers-console

I have an Android Wear app that the Developer Console reports is compatible with my device (Huawei Watch 2) and 26 others. Obviously, I've been using my device to develop it, and it work.

When I look for it in the Play Store on the watch itself, it shows up and seems to allow me to purchase it.

The Play Store, accessed from PC browser, claims that it is not compatible with any of my devices - specifically claiming that it is incompatible with the Huawei Watch 2.

Why would the Play Store from by PC browser claim that it's incompatible? I've done quite a bit of searching. I've added android:required="false" to appropriate permissions in the manifest. APK size is small (<7MB). I can't find anything else to investigate. Any ideas?

Here's my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.mendonphoto.run2gps">

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.type.watch" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" android:required="false"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BODY_SENSORS" android:required="false"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault">
    <uses-library
        android:name="com.google.android.wearable"
        android:required="false" />

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.Light">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.wearable.standalone"
        android:value="true" />

</application>
```

Comment: Is this a free or pay-before-install app?

Comment: pay-before-install

Answer (score 1):

Historically, this is the message that Google Play shows when you (the app publisher) look at a paid app from your own account. This is from Google Play support:

> Usually, the cause of the error you're seeing is due to the fact that developers can't purchase or download their own apps. If you’d like see what your apps look like from the perspective of a Google Play user, I recommend logging into Google Play with an email address other than the primary email address for your Developer Console. It's very likely all the devices are supported, this is just a common message to see when you're not allowed to download the app, in this case because it belongs to you.

[from https://stackoverflow.com/a/40244232/252080 ]

Answer (score -1):

You may want to check this [Device Compatibility](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/compatibility.html) documentation and in order for your app to be successful on all these devices, it should tolerate some feature variability and provide a flexible user interface that adapts to different screen configurations. In order for you to manage your app’s availability based on device features, Android defines feature IDs for any hardware or software feature that may not be available on all devices. For instance, the feature ID for the compass sensor is `FEATURE_SENSOR_COMPASS` and the feature ID for app widgets is `FEATURE_APP_WIDGETS`. Also from this [support page](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7353455?hl=en), your app's device compatibility list is based on the [manifest file settings](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html) and is refreshed periodically.

Comment: As you can see from my manifest above, I'm not requesting any features other than "android.hardware.type.watch". I have provided for an appropriate layout for any screen size. And, as mentioned, the developer console claims that my app is compatible with most Android Wear watches - even though the Play Store says it isn't.