# This app is incompatible with your device after change targetSdkVersion from 28 to 29

Tags: android, kotlin, versioning, targetsdkversion

I suffer a lot about this,
My previous app has targetSdkVersion 28 but now I changed it to targetSdkVersion 29 due to Google Play requirement.

It works well when I install it directly from AS to my phone, and it works too when I share the APK.
But after I upload it to Play Store, there is no device supported with this version.

I appreciate your help, thank you

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I can solve this issue.
The problem is in the manifest file. There is a line I should remove.
I should remove camera2 in the manifest file.

Just it, and now my app is on play store.
Thank you guys

Answer (score -1):

Try logging into Google Play with another email account. I'm not sure if this changed, but as of a couple years ago developers couldn't download their own apps from the store. So they'd show this misleading error message instead.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/40244232/7434090

Comment: All of my users cannot install it, it doesn't happen just for me but for all users. Even though, now my app disappear from GP

Answer (score -1):

You may want to check the app availability in your target users' country.

UPDATE:

Never mind this, if it's unavailable in your country, it should say `This app is not available in your country` instead.